# Put footer box behind content box

Tags: html, css

[image]

**I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS, so sorry if the question falls under the category of "elemental"**

What I want to happen is to set those two rounded corners from the top of the "footer div" look shard and basically make the "main body div" and "footer div" look like 1 (not counting the color difference).

My first thought was to push the footer div up with margin-top, and hide it behind the main body div with `z-index: -1;` It Does push the footer div up, but doesn't, however, put it behind the main body one. So it there any way to either make those top corners sharp, or simply hide those curved corners behind the main body div?

Sorry if the question is unclear, English isn't my native language. I'd be happy to answer anything that I've said unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily make the top corners sharp using border radius:

```
border-radius:0px 0px 15px 15px;
```

The values in the CSS are the amount of rounding given. The first value `(0px)` is the top left, then top right `(0px)`, bottom right `(15px)` and bottom left `(15px)`.
[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/Htb5S/)